# cout something before another c++

Tags: c++

I am supposed to write a program that reads n int variables ranging from 1 to n. The variables here represent the beginning set of a car race (ex 4 3 1 2) and the final set is always 1,2,3,4,.....n. 
I am asked to display the minimum numbers (s) of over passments (here 5) then the details of overpassments (here 3 1 then 4 1 then 3 2 then 4 2 then  4 3) I wrote a c++ code but I didn't find how to display (s) before the overpassments without resorting to store the overpassments in an array which takes me more than 16000 kb of memory 
here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std ;

int main()
{
int a;
cin>>a;
int t[a];
int t1[2002];
for (int i(0); i<a; i++)
    {cin>>t[i];t1[i]=t[i];}
int s=0;int it(0);
for (int i(1); i<=a; i++)
{
    int pos;
    int c=1;
    for (int j(0); j<a && c==1; j++)
    {
        if (t[j]==i)
        {
            pos=j;
            c=0;
        }
    }
    for (int j(1);j<=pos-i+1;j++)
    {
        int aux=t[pos-j];
        t1[it]=t[pos-j];
        t1[it+1]=t[pos-j+1];
        t[pos-j]=i;
        t[pos-j+1]=aux;
        s++;
        it+=2;
    }
}
cout<<s<<endl;
for (int i(0);i<it;i+=2)
{
    cout<<t1[i]<<" "<<t1[i+1]<<endl;
}



return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to nitpick, your code is technically not valid C++, [variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of C++, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: Instead of sorting/outputting strictly sequential, you could do both at the same time saving you the need to fill t1 at all. Besides, using 16MB RAM is not always the worst thing to do but for this case, it seems overkill.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use more memory, you can either use more cpu time (scan the array twice, the first time to count the number of overpasses, the second time to print them), or use more hard disk space (create a temporary file to hold the overpasses, print the content of the file on screen and at the end delete it).

Answer (score 0):

Your task description screams for an implementation of bubble sort.

As for displaying the number of swaps (which correspond to the overtakes) and the swaps itself: 
Just count the swaps, while you are executing the qlgorithm and display each swap right when you do it.